# Get last token from string in batch script

Tags: parsing, batch-file, directory

I am working on a batch script, and I need a way to remove the lowest-level directory from a full path string.  So for example, if I have:

C:/dir1/dir2/dir3

I would like my batch script to return "dir3."  This string, C:/dir1/dir2/dir3 is passed in by the user and set as the variable "FullPath".

I looked over the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473840/last-token-in-batch-variable), which appeared to be a similar problem, but the solutions there didn't make any use of delimiters.  And, the closest I've gotten to solving this is this code:

```
for /f "tokens=(some number) delims=\" %%a in ("%FullPath%") do echo Token=%%a
```

...this can echo any token I specify (I will eventually be setting this token to a variable, but I need to get the right one first), but I don't know how many tokens there will be, and I always want the last one in the string, as following the "\" character.

How can I edit this line of code to return the final token in the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("%fullpath%\.") do set "lastPart=%%~nxa"
```

That is, use a `for` loop to get a reference to the full path and from it retrieve the name and extension of the last element

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way:

```
for %%x in (%fullpath:\= %) do set last=%%x
```

This uses the same logic as the last answer but it does the standard `for` loop changing the delimiter from `\` to space with the `%var:=%` syntax. It's a trick to obtain the effect of `for /f "delims=\"`, using `for` instead of `for /f` which does not loop like plain `for`.

Answer (score 0):

if the tokens are separated/delimited by forward slashes ("/"), the last token is:

```
set b=C:/dir1/dir2/dir3
for %i in (%b:/=\%) do echo %~ni
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case, where I wanted only the name of the file from a link address.  This seemed to do the job:

```
@echo off
set PYZIP=https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/python-3.8.6-embed-win32.zip

for %%x in (%PYZIP:/= %) do set PYZIP_FILE=%%x
echo %PYZIP_FILE%
```

returns: `python-3.8.6-embed-win32.zip`

Comment: Your solutions have some drawbacks. It's slow, it fails for files like `C:\Program Files (x86)\file.txt` or `C:\temp\my file with spaces.txt`. Better use the modifiers `%%~nx<LOOP-VAR>`

Comment: true, but this is only directed at web link type addresses where there will not be spaces

Comment: That makes it a solution for your partial problem only and it still fails when there are other characters inside the link, like comma or semicolon.